# Benchmark website

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat, benchmarking

How can i benchmark a website ? i want to define how many user can i handle simultaneously. Can you suggest me any read / tool that helps ?

I don't think that matters but the site is a Flex application that consumes some services provided by tomcat's servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Bench 'ab'](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)

ab is a tool for benchmarking your Apache Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) server. It is designed to give you an impression of how your current Apache installation performs. This especially shows you how many requests per second your Apache installation is capable of serving.

*I'm assuming you're running *nix and have Apache installed... so....*

For Example:

If you want to send quantity 100 total requests, 10 requests at a time, type this command at your command prompt:

```
# ab -n 100 -c 10 http://www.somewhere.com/
```

Comment: i was aware of Apache ab, but what i don't know is how to use it to determine the max number of concurrent user. When the time for request drops under a limit that i'll fix or, for exemple, when the server start to loose connections ?

The other question is about the hardware. If i run ab from a single remote computer this can really simulate a big number of concurrent request or the limit of my bandwidth (normal DSL) stop ab to work properly ?

Thanks

Comment: You can generate lots of traffic from one computer. As for measuring concurrent connections, you have to do some profiling. None the less, you can manually up the # of concurrent connections until the site becomes unavailable. You may reach apache's max clients. You may hit a memory limit. Which may not be indicative of your code. Whatever the case, if you play around with ab long enough you're going to get the info you're after eventually.

Answer (score 1):

There are some website which offer a service like this. I know [Load Impact](http://loadimpact.com/) one which is free if you want to simulate up to 50 users at a time.